# Simple Javascript for form validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript

So, I have written this form and this simple javascript to validate the user input.
The thing is, it works perfectly until I add a third function, validateHash, that takes the hashtag inputed into the textbox and checks if it has an hashtag at the beginning.
I sent the code to a friend, and he said that on his PC it works fine (Checks if the fields are filled, and then checks if the hashtag is correct), while on mine it just skips every function and submits the data to the php page without checking anything. 
I am using Firefox, and he's using Chrome, but I tried even with the latter with the same results. 
Is there something wrong in the code itself?

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm() {
   if(validate(document.form.song.value) && validate(document.form.hashtag.value))
     if(validateHash(document.form.hashtag.value))
       return true;
    else
    {
      alert("Please fill all the fields");
      return false;
     }
  }

  function validate(text) {
    if(text==null || text=="")
      return false;
    else
      return true;
}

  function validateHash(text) {
    if(text.charAt(0) != "#") {
      alert("Insert hashtag correctly");
      return false;
      }
    else
      return true;
}

</script>

<form action="format.php" name="form" method="post" class="basic-grey" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <h1>Anisongs Form
    <span>Fill all the text in the fields</span>
  </h1>

  <label>
    <span>Song lyrics :</span>
    <textarea id="song" name="song" placeholder="Max 120 characters" maxlength="120"></textarea>
  </label>

  <label>
    <span>Anime hashtag :</span>
    <input id="hashtag" type="text" name="hashtag" placeholder="#loghorizon" maxlength="20"/>
  </label>


    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit" />
    <input type="reset" class="button" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

Comment: I suppose it's only `onsubmit="validateForm"`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (validate(document.form.song.value) && validate(document.form.hashtag.value) && validateHash(document.form.hashtag.value))`

Comment: @AmilWaduwawara — You suppose very wrongly.

Comment: Before adding validateHash() it worked even with onsubmit="return validateForm()", so I don't really think that's the issue...

If I put all the validations inside a single if I'll get the two alerts together, the one for filling the fields and the one for the missing hashtag, and I kinda wanted to avoid that.
Still, it seems it doesn't even pass through any function right now, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issues were the brackets. JS really fancies them, and without them even on single lines ifs it wouldn't start to work.